# VtkOpenGLRenderer errors after migration from vtk 5.3 to vtk 6.2

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-studio-2008, vtk

I am working on VisualStudio2008 on Windows 7 in C++.

I just changed of Vtk version 5.10 to 6.2, and my program runs as it is supposed to do but one thing, I have this kind of error messages in a vtkOutputWindow:

```
ERROR: In .\vtkOpenGLRenderer.cxx, line 126
vtkOpenGLRenderer (03A4D058): failed ater ClearLights 16 OpenGL errors detected
  0 : (1282) Invalid operation
...

ERROR: In .\vtkOpenGLRenderer.cxx, line 1202
vtkOpenGLRenderer (03A4D058): failed after Clear 16 OpenGL errors detected
  0 : (1282) Invalid operation
...

ERROR: In .\vtkOpenGLCamera.cxx, line 167
vtkOpenGLCamera (03A993E8): failed after Render 16 OpenGL errors detected
  0 : (1282) Invalid operation
...

ERROR: In .\vtkOpenGLLight.cxx, line 118
vtkOpenGLLight (03A9C038): failed after Render 16 OpenGL errors detected
  0 : (1282) Invalid operation
...

ERROR: In .\vtkOpenGLRenderer.cxx, line 192
vtkOpenGLRenderer (03A4D058): failed after UpdateLights 16 OpenGL errors detected
  0 : (1282) Invalid operation
 ...

ERROR: In .\vtkOpenGLRenderer.cxx, line 282
vtkOpenGLRenderer (03A4D058): failed after DeviceRender 16 OpenGL errors detected
  0 : (1282) Invalid operation
....
```

I really don't know where it comes from, I added these lines to the beginning of my project (as I saw on the internet) to fix the change of version but there is still those messages:

```
  #include <vtkVersion.h>
    #include <vtkAutoInit.h>
    VTK_MODULE_INIT(vtkRenderingOpenGL);
    #define vtkRenderingCore_AUTOINIT  4(vtkInteractionStyle,vtkRenderingFreeType,vtkRenderingFreeTypeOpenGL,vtkRenderingOpenGL)
    #define vtkRenderingVolume_AUTOINIT 1(vtkRenderingVolumeOpenGL)
```

Does someone have an idea?

Answer (score -3):

I finally got the answer by myself, I needed to delete the `ren->Render()` line.